# Laravel: delete photo by photo id

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to delete a photo by it's id, but the routes do not work and I receive a MethodNotAllowedHttpException. What I do:

First I create a form (in my blade template):

```
{{ Form::open(array("action" => array("cms/albums/destroyphoto", $photo['id']), "method" => "DELETE")) }}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then i create my route:

```
Route::post('cms/albums/destroyphoto/{id}', 'AlbumsController@destroyphoto');
```

And create my function in the Albumscontroller:

```
public function destroyphoto($id)
{
    dd('Welcome photo');
}
```

Any suggestions where the routing goes wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Ps. I did composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open your form using `"action"` you should pass the controller class and action name. You also don't need to specify the `method` since you're using `Route::post`

Like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array("action" => array("AlbumsController@destroyphoto", $photo['id']))) }}
```

[More information](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)